# SQL query to find maximum salary

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
----------------------
| ID | Name | Salary |
| -- | ---  | ---    |
| 1  |  A   | 1000   |
| 2  |  B   | 4000   |
| 3  |  C   | 5000   |
| 4  |  B   |  600   |
| 5  |  C   | 2000   |
| 6  |  A   | 5000   |
| 7  |  B   | 4000   |
----------------------
```

And I want to query the maximum salary in the whole table and the maximum salary of each student. I can write two queries like,

```
>> SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM TABLE
>> SELECT NAME, MAX(SALARY) FROM TABLE GROUP BY NAME
```

Now, I want to do the same in a **single query** without using two queries. How do I approach?

Comment: MySQL returns similarly structured rows for a query, but these two queries produce different structures. What do you want your output to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ROLLUP can be used to give an extra row as a 'summary', and so give the overall MAX value...

```
  SELECT name, MAX(salary)
    FROM TABLE
GROUP BY name
    WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY GROUPING(name) DESC,
         name
```

Which would yield...

```
| Name | Salary |
| ---  | ---    |
| NULL | 5000   |
|  A   | 5000   |
|  B   | 4000   |
|  C   | 5000   |
```

Comment: Can the last row >> NULL | 5000, come to the top. I want the last row at the top.

Comment: @HariTunes you just need a subselect for that `select name, max_salary from (select name, max(salary) max_salary from mysterytablename group by name with rollup) maxsalaries order by name is
not null, name;` (assuming name can never be null; if it can, it's more complicated)

Comment: @HariTunes - Yes, `ORDER BY GROUPING(name) DESC` will put the summary row first.

Comment: (subselect approach needed in mysql before 8.0.12 or mariadb)

Answer (score 1):

here is one way:

```
SELECT NAME, MAX(SALARY) , max(max(salary)) over() 
FROM TABLE GROUP BY NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) to group around the `Name` field and [`ORDER BY ... DESC`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sorting-rows.html) on the `Salary` field to get the max.

```
SELECT PrimaryField, MaxField
FROM MyTable
GROUP By PrimaryField
ORDER BY MaxField DESC;
```

Explanation:

- `SELECT PrimaryField, MaxField` — The fields we want.
- `FROM MyTable` — The table we want.
- `GROUP By PrimaryField` — What we want to be treated as a primary field.
- `ORDER BY MaxField DESC;` — Since we group by `PrimaryField`, we get only one row for each `PrimaryField` unique value.  If we order the MaxField, we can get the min or max of it as needed.

For you specifically:

```
SELECT Name, Salary
FROM TABLE
GROUP By Name
ORDER BY Salary DESC;
```